# Копирование данных из одной таблицы в другую с "поворотом" (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

Подскажите простой прособ перезаписать данные из одной таблицы (postgresql) в другую с "поворотом" данных (из таблицы с записью состаяния в таблицу с времянными рядами):
из

```
name | status
_____________
'a'  | 1
'b'  | 2
```

в

```
timestamp            | a | b
-----------------------------
2022-07-01 20:00:01  | 1 | 2
```

Answer (score 1):

##### Конкретно для приведенного примера

```sql
insert into dest_tab select current_timestamp, a, b 
     from lateral (select status from src_tab where name = 'a') s1(a), 
          lateral (select status from src_tab where name = 'b') s2(b)
```

> Это при условии что в `src_tab` значения поля `name` уникальны